# Get location media from instagram api

Tags: oauth-2.0, instagram-api

So, I have a situation here. My client wants to get location media from instagram without access token, authorized app, etc... Can this be achieved?

If not, please tell me how to start a submission for this permission, and what permission exactly is this with instagram.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean get media by geolocation?

`GET https://www.instagram.com/explore/locations/<LOCATION_ID>/?__a=1`

without any authorization and application, for example

`curl https://www.instagram.com/explore/locations/212988663/?__a=1`

for New York and then parse json

Comment: You are a life savior Sir! Thank you.